# Opening Database connection is failing via JNDI in WAS 8.5

Tags: java, database, websphere, jndi

We have a Application called AQS which needs to be migrated from WAS 7 to WAS 8.5.

I have this JNDI defined in our code,

```
 private static final String JNDI_NAME_AQSSERVICE = "java:comp/env/jdbc/aqsservice/AQS";
```

Also the same JNDI URL is defined in our WAS 8.5 Admin Console and Test Connection is successful.

Below is the method we are using for opening DB connection:

```
    public Connection getAQSDBConnection() throws ConnectionManagerException
{
    try
    {
        Connection con = DataSourceManager.getConnection(JNDI_NAME_AQSSERVICE);


         if(log.isEnabledFor(Priority.INFO))
                log.info("DB Connection retrieved in ConnectionManager.getAQSDBConnection()");

        if (con != null)
            con.setAutoCommit(false); // turn auto-commit OFF

        return con;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception while retrieving DB Connection in ConnectionManager.getAQSDBConnection() is :" + e);
        throw new ConnectionManagerException("ConnectionManager.getDBConnection(): Exception occurred while opening database connection.", e);
    }
}
```

When trying to open DB connection via our code, we are getting runtime exception like below:

```
[4/24/18 11:25:45:298 CDT] 00000070 SystemOut     O Exception while retrieving DB Connection in ConnectionManager.getAQSDBConnection() is :javax.naming.ConfigurationException: Malformed provider URL ""
```

We have double checked the JNDI URL is same in Code and WAS 8.5 Admin console, but it coming as blank when opening the connection. The same code is working in WAS 7 environment.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: DataSourceManager is not WAS code.  Is it your code (if so can you post where in the source it does the JNDI lookup) or third party code?

Comment: I did a quick search with the JNDI name and there are nothing except some XML entries in web.xml of my web module. So I guess it is done by Third Party Code?

Comment: Just look for the package name for the `DataSourceManager` class. But in general you should replace it with `IntitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(); con = ctx.lookup(JNDI_NAME_AQSSERVICE);`